# Why are non-linear activation functions required in multilayer perceptron classification?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Solution: for some reason, I had forgotten that the non-linear activation function is applied at every layer of the neural network, not just at the output layer. Hopefully to others reading my original question below will understand why I asked it. Thank you for the answers, though.

Original: Suppose I have a multilayer perceptron network of a couple of layers with some output nodes that will be subject to the classic sigmoid activation function - how will this change which output node will have the highest value for a given input vector (and is selected as the final classification)? Namely, (denoting the sigmoid function as f(x)) if x' > x, f(x') > x, meaning the same output node will be selected as the final classification.

I think I am missing something about its importance in gradient descent or the determination of loss but please clarify this for me if you know my thinking error.

Comment: Write out a small network with one input variable, two nodes in the hidden layer, one output node, and linear activation functions. Write out the equation that forms. Does it look familiar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-linear activation functions are needed because a linear combination of linear functions is still a linear function. So without non-linear activation functions, the multilayered perceptron won't be able to learn non-linear relationships from the data, basically it would have the same capabilities as "network" with only one neuron. So if there is a non-linear relationship between input and output, or there are interactions between variables, the network won't be able to learn these things.

Comment: I don't feel like this really answers my question. How does the non-linear activation change the classification chosen from what would be chosen without the non-linear activation function?

Edit: Given that the selection rule is that the classification is chosen based on the highest output node value.

Comment: @User if you are asking why have output node with a non-linear activation function and not just linear, this is because usually you code your targets as 1 or 0, and with a sigmoid function, the network can only output numbers between 0 and 1, but if it's a linear function, than outputs are not bounded, but the errors are still counted based on your 0-1 coding of the target variable.

Answer (score -1):

with your question, you can come back to the problem of XOR function that once was not solved by NNs without non-linear activation functions whereby NNs lost their attention until non-linear functions were involved.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582251/can-an-ann-2-2-1-layers-be-implemented-to-learn-xor-using-linear-activation-fu

https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-the-XOR-problem-be-solved-by-a-one-layer-perceptron